# How can I derive this exponential function given its form and some points?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

This is for a [silly simulation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182453/simple-simulated-people-how-should-health-energy-and-nutrition-interact) I am working on. The details of why I want this function are not important for this question but if you are interested you can follow the link.

I want a function $f$ that satisfies the following properties
$$p1:f(1)=0$$
$$p2:f(0)=a; a >> 1$$
$$p3:f(b)=1$$

What I want is a line that starts steep at $f(0) = a$ and transitions smoothly to being less steep at $f(1)=0$.
I figure if I take an exponential function with an appropriate base and translate it vertically and horizontally that would work well.

So I am looking for a function of the form $$f(x)=c^{x+d}+e$$

So given $a,b$, solve for $c,d,e$.
My attempts at solving this analytically have not gone well.
I suppose I could solve this using some sort of gradient decent, but is it possible in closed form? Lambert's product log and similar are permitted. Does this specification result in a unique solution. I suspect it does.

Comment: There is a problem. Your graph has a minimum on interval (0,b). The exponential function you are trying to use, does not. This can be avoided if $b$ is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Also: Probably a good idea to set $c = 2$ or $c = e \approx 2.7183$, and then write $f(x) = e^{px + q} + d$. That'll be easier to work with.

Comment: @imranfat i forgot to mention that the x is restricted to be between 0 and 1. But even without that restriction, I can't see a way to get a minimum on (0,b) for all possible c, d, and e. Can you give an example? Isn't the function monotonic?

Comment: If the domain of $x$ is between 0 and 1, why not pick a quadratic polynomial function instead?

Comment: @imranfat I tried that but couldn't guarantee non-negativity for all a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
f(x) = \exp(px + q) + d.
$$
From $f(0) = a$, get
$$
a = \exp(q) + d.
$$
From $f(1) = 0$, get
$$
\exp(p + q) + d= 0
$$
so that
$$ 
d  = -\exp(p+q). 
$$
So now your formula is 
$$
f(x) = \exp(px + q) - \exp(p + q),
$$
and the fact about $a$ now reads
$$
a = \exp(q) - \exp(p + q) = \exp(\frac{p}{p+q}) \tag{A}
$$

From $f(b) = 1$, you get
$$
1 = \exp(pb + q) - \exp(p+q)
$$
Taking the difference of these last two gives
$$
a-1 = \exp(q) - \exp(pb + q) = \exp(\frac{q}{pb + q})
$$
so that
$$
\ln (a-1) = \frac{q}{pb+q}.
$$
and from formula A, we have
$$
\ln(a) = \frac{p}{p+q}
$$
Knowing $a$ and $b$, this amounts to a pair of linear equations in $p$ and $q$, which you can (generally) solve. Of course, it makes no sense if either $a < 0$ or $a -1 < 0$, for in that case, the logarithms on the LHS are undefined.

Of course, not every pair of simultaneous linear equations in two unknowns has a solution (example: $x + y = 1 ; x + y = 2$), and it's possible that for some values of $a$ and $b$, your equations will be unsolvable as well.

Comment: I like this idea and am going to explore it a bit. Are you saying there is no closed form solution to the problem as posed?

Comment: I think there is a mistake somewhere here. I couldn't find a solution given your last 2 statements. I found a solution numerically (a=2, b=0.1, q=0.694138, p=-6.92313) which does not agree with your last 2 statements.

Comment: Right...I screwed up the algebra typing too fast, and the revised version doesn't seem to have a pretty answer, but I'll fiddle a little bit more.